# PHP blog not saving data to file as expected

Tags: php

For some reason when I fill in the form and click submit, it does not put the information into the .txt file.

```
  <table id="hor-zebra" summary="Employee Pay Sheet">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="27%" scope="col">Name</th>
            <th width="31%" scope="col">Email</th>
            <th width="42%" scope="col">Comment</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="odd">

        </tr>
        <tr>

        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">

        </tr>
        <tr>

        </tr>
        <?php  
    $blogFile = 'blog.txt';
    if (file_exists($blogFile))
    {
        $readfile = file($blogFile);
        for ($k=0; $k<=count($readfile)-1; $k++) {
            $fields = split("\t",$readfile[$k]);
            print("<tr>");
            print("<td>$fields[0]</td>");
            print("<td>$fields[1]</td>");
            print("<td>$fields[2]</td>");
            print("</tr>");
        }
    }
?>
    </tbody>
</table>
                                    <h2>Blog</h2>
                                    <form method="post" action="writeBlog.php">
                <div class="row half">
                    <div class="6u">
                        <input type="text" class="text" name="Name" id="Name" placeholder="Name" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="6u">
                        <input type="text" class="text" name="Email" id="Email" placeholder="Email" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row half">
                    <div class="12u">
                        <textarea name="Comment" placeholder="Comment" id="Comment"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="12u"> <a href="writeBlog.php" class="button">Submit comment</a> </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

and here is the php code that handles the from.

```
<?php 
$out = fopen("blog.txt", "a");
if (!$out) { 
    header('Location: blog.php');
    exit;
}
$Name = $_POST['Name'];
$Email = $_POST['Email'];
$Comment = $_POST['Comment'];
$Comment = str_replace("\n", " ", $Comment);    

fputs($out,"$Name\t");
fputs($out,"$Email\t");
fputs($out,"$Comment\n");

fclose ($out); 
    header('Location: blog.php');
    exit;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Why does this code not put the information into the .txt file?

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: don't get an error the info for the table does not show up on the txt file that is created

Comment: What do you get when you var_dump($_POST), I don't see that you are submitting the data correctly, add a submit button to the form, All I see in your form is a href as a submit button which will not work unless you have some JS that handles it

Comment: i think that is the problem. is there a way to keep <div class="12u"> <a href="writeBlog.php" class="button">Submit comment</a> </div> as a submit button

Comment: Why do you need that in the form? the data will be submitted to "writeBlog.php" because it is the "action" of your form.

Comment: The .txt file holds the info when you click the submit button, the writeBlog.php takes what you have submitted and writes it into the .txt file, which then takes the info back to the blog.php and into the table that holds all of the comments. However, the .txt file is not taking this information and it is placing it directly to the blog.php table without writing it into the blog.txt file...

Comment: This `<a href="writeBlog.php" class="button">Submit comment</a>` doesn't do what you expect it to do; use an actual submit button and not an `href` link to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `<a href="writeBlog.php" class="button">Submit comment</a>` doesn't do what you're expecting it to do; use an actual submit button and not an `href` link to a file.

Replace

```
<a href="writeBlog.php" class="button">Submit comment</a>
```

with

```
<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Submit comment">
```

---

Your form's action already takes care of that.

```
<form method="post" action="writeBlog.php">
```

Comment: thank you i did do this but you have just confirm the what i have done is correct tank you fred